# How do I fit a UV texture into a frame and dissolve glitches?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

Hello, I want to scale the door picture in my UV editor to my door surface in my 3d model, so I would like to know what would be a way to make it slimmer and positioning it to the center? I cant use loop cuts on the door surface because of already dissolved edges to fit the texture in a better "frame".
Also as you can see there is a huge glitch in the selected door. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: if you want the door to be narrower, maybe subdivide this part and give another material to the other parts you'll create?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps UV > Project From View Bounds is what you need ?

1. In Edit mode Select only your door.
2. Go into Front Orthographic view.
3. Open the UV drop-down menu and choose the **Project From View (Bounds)** option.

The door image in the UV editor should now be mapped perfectly to your door mesh. If the door is too wide then select the door mesh and scale it in the X ( or Y ) axis.

[image]